# Python/Pyspark : Remove postalcode from the address column

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a column which has the addresses like below -

```
Address

5 HARBOURplace st. HARBOURFRONT T 98899
PULAV AYTR CHAIWAN 98644
4500 BAYTOWN DRIVE, ROOM 2466 77555
77210 
22567 SPRINGlane VILLAGE drive 77355-1445
PO BOX 2422 F2K 6L2
FERKERN 30 4044
ATTN : PALACE SHIP 7654
```

I want to separate postalcode out of it to another column like below

```
Address                                postalcode
PULAV AYTR CHAIWAN                       98644
4500 BAYTOWN DRIVE, ROOM 2466            77555
                                         77210 
22567 SPRINGlane VILLAGE drive        77355-1445
PO BOX 2422 F2K 6L2
FERKERN 30                               4044
ATTN : PALACE SHIP                       7654
```

I am trying this -

```
df['zip'] = df['address'].str.extract(r'(\d{5}\-?\d{0,4})')
```

but it splits only 5 digits and also pick up house number if it is of 5 digit like 5th record below. Also it does not remove postalcode from address column

```
Address                                         postalcode
5 HARBOURplace st. HARBOURFRONT T 98899            98899
PULAV AYTR CHAIWAN 98644                           98644
4500 BAYTOWN DRIVE, ROOM 2466 77555                77555
77210                                              77210
22567 SPRINGlane VILLAGE drive 77355-1445          22567
PO BOX 2422 F2K 6L2
FERKERN 30 4044
ATTN : PALACE SHIP 7654
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: If you are using Pandas , you should have tagged 'pandas' instead of pyspark

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the postal code is always at the end of the address text and is always a numeric value, you may try this -

```py
df['zip'] = df['address'].apply(lambda x: str(x.split(" ")[-1]) if str(x.split(" ")[-1]).replace("-", "").isnumeric() else "")
```

Otherwise, you would need a better pattern matching regex.

Edit: Removing postal code from original address value

Once the postal code is extracted into a separate column, concatenate the remaining list elements in the split

```py
df['address'] = df['address'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.split(" ")[:-1]) if str(x.split(" ")[-1]).replace("-","").isnumeric() else " ".join(x.split(" ")))
```

Comment: Thanks and how to remove the zip from the address column also?

Comment: edited to complete the answer with a slight modification to handle "-" in the postal code

Comment: If it works for you, could you please accept the answer? It can help motivate me in providing more answers on Stackoverflow.